# visual studio 2015 build type or name space could not be found cs0246

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution which I copied from one computer to another computer. I am using VS2015 to build it. It contains 37 project. 2 projects cannot be build which reference to a dll in another project, say "Abc.Common". I found the dll is already 
included but it just say

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Abc' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Any clue that I can solve it?

Comment: just to clarify, are those two external DLLs or are they the output of other projects inside the .sln?

Comment: They are the output of other projects inside the .sln

Comment: in that case: Make sure that the dlls are not added as direct references but as project references. If that is already the case, another issue might be that the affected projects use different .NET versions that are not compatible to eachother.

Comment: I will try the answer in the coming days.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any clue that I can solve it?

You can check the references of those two projects in Solution Explorer who throw the error.

Whether there's a yellow triangle like this:

[image]

It indicates that your project failed to find the assembly or to load it. I'm not sure
what do you mean `I found the dll is already included`, but I suggest you can remove the reference from those two projects, and add it back again to check if it helps.

If the yellow warning is still there, maybe like what **Steffen** comments, the target framework of the assembly is higher than that of your current project, you can `go=>project=>properties` to change the target framework to higher versions to resolve the issue.

Also, you can `Go View menu=>Error List` to open `Error List window`, you may find the clue why this issue occurs there. (Choose the `Build+Intellisense`)

After that if the issue still persists,right-click the project=>Build Dependencies=>Project Build Order, make sure those two projects are built after the build of the assembly project (Abc.Common).

Some description and the possible causes about the CS0246 error message see [Compiler Error CS0246](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246).